# Emacs (24.4.2) Gnus (0.12) TLS connection not working

Tags: emacs, openssl, gnus, starttls

Recently, I've been experiencing problems with my email setup using Emacs (24.4.2) + Gnus (0.12).  It seems that the TSL connection is not working:

```
gnutls.c: [0] (Emacs) fatal error: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
gnutls.el: (err=[-110] The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.) boot: (:priority NORMAL       :hostname smtp.me.com :loglevel 0 :min-prime-bits 256 :trustfiles nil :crlfiles nil :keylist nil             :verify-flags nil :verify-error nil :callbacks nil)
smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed: 530 5.7.0 No STARTTLS command has been given.
```

Is it a Gnus or Openssl problem? How should I debug and fix it?

Here is the output of the smtp trace buffer:

```
220 nk11p00mm-asmtp003.example.com -- Server ESMTP (Oracle Communications Messaging Server 7u4-27.10(7.0.4.27.9) 64bit (built Jun  6 2014))
250-nk11p00mm-asmtp003.example.com
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-EXPN
250-HELP
250-XADR
250-XSTA
250-XCIR
250-XGEN
250-XLOOP 098E7F59418D8F04E0C7135651497A4E
250-STARTTLS
250-NO-SOLICITING
250 SIZE 28311552
220 2.5.0 Go ahead with TLS negotiation.

Process smtpmail deleted
220 nk11p00mm-asmtp003.example.com -- Server ESMTP (Oracle Communications Messaging Server 7u4-27.10(7.0.4.27.9) 64bit (built Jun  6 2014))
MAIL FROM:<john.doe@example.com>
250-nk11p00mm-asmtp003.example.com
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-EXPN
250-HELP
250-XADR
250-XSTA
250-XCIR
250-XGEN
250-XLOOP 098E7F59418D8F04E0C7135651497A4E
250-STARTTLS
250-NO-SOLICITING
250 SIZE 28311552
RCPT TO:<john.doe@example.com>
530 5.7.0 No STARTTLS command has been given.
QUIT
503 5.5.0 No MAIL FROM command has been issued.
```

Comment: Try setting `smtpmail-debug-info` to `t`.  That should create a buffer called `*trace of SMTP session to <somewhere>*`, which should make it clearer what's going on.  Also, what's the value of `smtpmail-stream-type`?

Comment: @legoscia The value of the `smtpmail-stream-type` is `nil`. I've edited the question and added the output of the `*trace of SMTP session to smtp.me.com*` buffer.

Comment: Was this resolved? You could try looking at this question and compare your setup [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591415/trouble-opening-gmail-nnimap-server-in-emacs-gnus-on-windows/20642600#20642600]