# Configuring gnus with gmail imap

Tags: emacs, openssl, imap, gnus

I am trying to configure gnus to work with my gmail account. My .gnus file looks like this:

```
(setq gnus-select-method '(nntp "news.gwene.org"))

(setq user-full-name "George P. Burdell")
(setq user-mail-address "probablyReal@gmail.com")

(setq smtpmail-auth-credentials "~/.authinfo.epg")
(add-to-list 'gnus-secondary-select-methods
        '(nnimap "gmail"
           (nnimap-address "imap.gmail.com")
           (nnimap-server-port 993)
           (nnimap-stream ssl)
           (nnimap-authinfo-file "~/.authinfo.epg")
           )
        )
(setq smtpmail-stream-type 'ssl
       smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
       smtpmail-smtp-service 465)
```

and my .authinfo.epg file looks like this:

```
machine imap.gmail.com login probablyReal@gmail.com password secret port 993
machine smtp.gmail.com login probablyReal@gmail.com password secret port 465
```

and the error that it throws is:

```
Generating the cache active file...done
Opening nnfolder server on archive...done
Opening nnimap server on gmail...
Opening connection to imap.gmail.com via tls...
Opening TLS connection to `imap.gmail.com'...
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 993 imap.gmail.com'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 993 imap.gmail.com --protocols ssl3'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -no_ssl2 -ign_eof'...failed
Opening TLS connection to `imap.gmail.com'...failed
Unable to open server nnimap+gmail due to: Buffer  *nnimap imap.gmail.com 993  *nntpd** has no process
Opening nnimap server on gmail...failed: 
No new newsgroups
Checking new news...
Reading active file from gmail via nnimap...
Opening nnimap server on gmail...
Server nnimap+gmail previously determined to be down; not retrying
Opening nnimap server on gmail...failed: 
Reading active file via nndraft...done
Checking new news...done
Warning: Opening nnimap server on gmail...failed: ; Server nnimap+gmail previously determined to be down; not retrying; Opening nnimap server on gmail...failed: ; Unable to open server nnimap+gmail due to: Buffer  *nnimap imap.gmail.com 993  *nntpd** has no process
```

(sorry for wall of text)

finally, when I evaluate this:

```
(gnutls-available-p)
```

it simply prints:

```
nil
```

I'm running emacs for windows 8, I'm *not* using cygwin, and I really can't figure out what the problem is, even after seraching for hours.

edit: I've tried both of these (as well as combinations from both) and get the same errors:

http://blog.binchen.org/posts/notes-on-using-gnus.html

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail

Comment: Have you compared your configuration to the wiki gmail setup to see if you are doing what has already been known to work correctly?  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail  Perhaps you are doing something different?

Comment: @lawlist I've looked at that config, as well as the config here: http://blog.binchen.org/posts/notes-on-using-gnus.html
Both options (and combinations of either) throw the same issues.

Comment: Take a look at this question, some relevant points: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591415/trouble-opening-gmail-nnimap-server-in-emacs-gnus-on-windows/20642600#20642600]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that Emacs on Windows doesn't come with the required libraries, hence `(gnutls-available-p)` returns nil for you. You'll have to install gnutls somewhere so that your Emacs will be able to find it, cf. the [GnuTLS homepage](http://gnutls.org/). You probably have to put the downloaded Windows library into the directory where Emacs is looking for it's libraries.